# change in excel file and export it into database

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008

I am working on a project where I download an Excel file from a website and have to do some modification in its some column and then upload it into the database.

I want to know is there any way to modify that Excel file automatically then then upload into the database?

[image: file]

example:this is the file which i download from website.

[image: updated file]

like id there are many column which i need to modify before export that file into SQL Server database table.

Comment: Yes, you can write a VBA script which will modify the spreadsheet.  Or, you could export it as flat CSV file and again write a script to modify it before importing to the database.  Can you be more specific here?

Comment: thank. can you give me some links where i  can learn it more specificaly

Comment: To be honest with you, if all you need to do is zero out a column, you can handle this easily enough from SQL Server.  Do you need to _add_ new columns, or just modify existing ones?  And, what are the real changes you need to make?

Comment: i have to modify existing ones and also make some new column to match to sql table values. my problem is i have to download so may files in 1 day and then do this work again and again. i need a solution where i can upload or give a path of file which add some column and modify the existing column. the values new columns is already predefined or constant.

Comment: Again, why can't you do this in SQL Server?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention  1 thing i can make a script to do this changes but the file i download is excel and  i am using bulk insert to export the file into database so i have to change it into .csv formate. is there anymore way to export the file into database from which can change format excel to csv or which directly upload it from excel format